# Execute Javascript only on specific URL with # appended

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to execute JS on a certain page with hashtags in the URL. I need to execute the JS only on #product2 and then hide on others.

My URL pattern is `/about#product1`, `/about#product2`, `/about#product3`, etc and the JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if( window.location.href.indexOf('/about#product2') !== -1 ) {
   alert('Hello');
}
</script>
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: What is the problem in above code?

Comment: It cannot detect `about#product2`. It works only on `/about`. I need to execute the Javascript only on `about#product2` and hide on others.

Comment: [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash) would be sufficient to compare.

Comment: `echo '<script>alert("hello");</script>';` — That's PHP. You can't switch programming languages mid-function.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen: How? Could you show a code example? The link shows an example only on ElementID. I'm not proficient in JS.

Comment: @Quentin: Just a simple `alert('hello');` would do.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you looking for the answer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (window.location.href.match(/\#product2/))
    {
      alert('hello');
    }
</script>
```